# CRS different after r.reclass through QGIS different than source raster

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis

According to the properties, my output raster is in a different projection than the input after running GRASS r.reclass through QGIS. Does anyone know if this is just a fluke and I can simply select a different CRS through the properties, or do I have to "Save as" to reproject the output raster in the correct CRS?

Using QGIS 2.14.3

Comment: Still having problems with this. Both the project CRS and the input raster CRS are the same (ESPG 31370), double checked that. But the CRS of output raster coming from r.rclass is not 31370 as expected from the answer above, but unknown. For one raster it's ok setting its CRS manually, but for many.... no. My code: input = 'input.tif' output = 'output.tif' p_rule='3=1' result=processing.run("grass7:r.reclass", { 'input':input, 'rules':'', 'txtrules':p_rule, 'output':output, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_ME

Answer (score 1):

Before you run GRASS, make sure that the project CRS is set to the CRS of the layer you are working on. Then output and input layer CRS should be the same.

`Save As` is not useful for reprojecting rasters (it only works for vector data). Instead, use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to a different filename and CRS, or `Set Layer CRS` **ONLY** if the raster is misplaced.

Comment: perfect! I did not know that the Save As: only works for vector data. Thanks AndreJ.

Comment: @Scolopax Save As works for rasters too, but only the filename part.