# QGIS: r.reclass changes output CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, grass-gis

Although this question has been asked [before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198426/crs-different-after-r-reclass-through-qgis-different-than-source-raster), my case seems to be different. If I have a raster in QGIS that has it's [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) set to `EPSG:26915` (NAD83 / UTM zone 15N) and I reclassify it using [`r.reclass`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/r.reclass.html), the output raster has a CRS of `EPSG:3159` (NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 15N).

This happens regardless of what my project CRS is set to or what the default CRS is set to in "Settings/Options/CRS". If, however, I warp my original raster to another CRS (e.g., `EPSG:32615` WGS84 / UTM zone 15 N), `r.reclass` of the warped layer yields a reclassified output that is in the same CRS as the warped layer.

I understand that the difference between NAD83 and NAD83(CSRS) is small; however, for some programs (e.g., R) that require layers to have the same projection before analysis, this behavior can be troublesome. Is there any way to set [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org) or [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) up to behave differently?

I am running QGIS 3.12.0 and GRASS 7.6.0 on a Debian 10 machine.

Comment: (Un)related question: GRASS 7.7 is pretty old and was never released, any chance to update to GRASS GIS 7.8? Or do you mean 7.6.0? I ask because there were significant changes concerning the projection management.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I edited the question to fix the Grass version typo. Unfortunately 7.6 is the version in the stable Debian repos. I can try this on a Debian testing machine later this week (7.8.2 is the Grass version on testing).

Comment: Importantly, GRASS GIS 7.8 comes with Python 3, PROJ 6 and GDAL 3 compatibility, so, highly recommended :-) https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/NewFeatures78